# Triggering a method at times stored in Array using NSTimer

Tags: ios, nsarray, nstimer, nstimeinterval

I have an Array that have stored times. I want NStimer to trigger at times stored in that array. For example, in array a[] i have 2, 5 and 10 seconds and want NSTimer to trigger a method at these times. I do have another NSTimer that keep updating the time instance variable every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution would be to loop through your array and schedule method calls with GCD

```
for (NSNumber *time in array) {
    NSTimeInterval delay = [time doubleValue];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
        });
}
```

Comment: What would i do if my times are in milliseconds, and if i have to pause the array and also have to read from different points in array . Because for loop won't stop and keep executing till the end point